# Image on Stripe modal not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am using the Stripe Checkout function and the image does not appear on the modal in production.

The view looks like:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                            data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
                            data-description="Sign up for the event!"
                            data-billing-address="true"
                            data-amount="1000"
                            data-image="/assets/crum.jpeg"
                            data-locale="auto"
                            data-label="Pay Entry Fee"
                            data-currency="eur">
                            </script>
```

I have raked the assets. It works locally, however the image does not appear at the top of the modal.

Comment: I believe Stripe Checkout requires the absolute path to the file (ie. with the host included).

Comment: config.assets.compile = true  config.assets.digest = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config/environments/production.rb  the following was marked as false for the default values.

```
config.assets.compile = true  
config.assets.digest = true
```

After changing the following run:

```
rake assets:precompile
```